# TRUE < FALSE in MS Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I wanted to do `OR` on boolean column in aggregate function of `group by` and, logically, I chose `Max` function for this. But I found out that `TRUE < FALSE` in MS Access! It seems that MS Access is aliasing `TRUE` to `-1` instead of `1`.

I tried the same in MySQL, seems working fine:

```
mysql> select if(TRUE > FALSE, 1, 0);
+------------------------+
| if(TRUE > FALSE, 1, 0) |
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
```

Why is that? Why on earth Access broke the SQL norm here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8827633/1324019

Comment: I don't think there is any SQL norm regarding mapping boolean values to integer values.

Comment: You are talking about Microsoft Access, why do you expect any kind of standards compliant behavior ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "Yes" a value of -1 in MS Access database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827447/why-is-yes-a-value-of-1-in-ms-access-database)

Comment: Seems to me that TRUE/FALSE should only ever be treated as truth values and as such do not have a magnitude. This renders discussions as to whether `TRUE > FALSE` pointless. After all does it make any sense that `TRUE + 1 = FALSE`? No it doesn't so why should anybody be concerned whether `TRUE > FALSE`? They shouldn't, and that is the answer.

Comment: I don't think so. Aggregate functions like Max and Min should work. There's no other way how to do groupwise AND/OR.

Comment: @NealB SQL:2011 Foundation section _8.2 Comparison predicate_ states: _"In comparisons of boolean values, True is greater than False"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in MSAccess the Value of true is -1.

It may have something to do with it's Visual Basic roots (in VB -1 is true to help it's BITWISE operators do double duty as logical operators), but I wouldn't be so surprised, MSAccess breaks many *many* SQL Norms.

Answer (score 2):

From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827447/why-is-yes-a-value-of-1-in-ms-access-database/8827633#8827633):

> The binary representation of False is 0000000000000000. If you perform a NOT operation (in machine code) to it, it will be changed to 1111111111111111, but this is the binary representation of the 16-bit signed integer -1.
>
> Changing the sign of a number happens by inverting all the bits and adding 1. This is called the "two's complement".
>
> Let us change the sign of 1111111111111111. First invert; we get: 0000000000000000
>
> Then add one: 0000000000000001, this is 1.
>
> This is the proof that 1111111111111111 was the binary representation of -1.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is an explanation, because e.g. in `C`, `!0 == 1`, not `11111111`. So `NOT` in the Access could have been implemented as `!`, not as bitwise `NOT`. I think this is just a broken design.

Comment: Anyway, why didn't they use `unsigned` types then? Then TRUE could be `11111111` and at the same time `> FALSE`.

Comment: "Anyway, why didn't they use unsigned types then"? Because it's built on the VB runtime, and the VB runtime didn't have unsigned types. "But when didn't the VB Runtime . . ." I dunno mate, it was a bad decision that bit me in the arse more than once I can tell you :(