# Querying a Yes/No field in an Access database from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a registration form for employees and members. When creating an account for members and employees there must be a difference when creating the account because they will have different options. I check a box to differentiate employee from member and save it in the database. My question is how can I query the database to know if the box is checked or not. This is what I have but it does not work.

```
Dim login = Me.LibraryMembersTableAdapter1.IDPass(txtID.Text, txtPass.Text)

Dim EmployeeCheck = LibraryMembersTableAdapter1.EmployeeCheck(Employee:=True)

If login Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Input Error")
Else
    MsgBox("Welcome!")
End If

If EmployeeCheck = True Then
    frmEmployee.Show()
Else
    Member.Show()
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes/No boxes are bits.  Their values are -1 and 0 respectively.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827447/why-is-yes-a-value-of-1-in-ms-access-database) for more info, which is quite similar.

Comment: If this answer helped, feel free to give it an upvote or the Accepted Answer checkmark (or both) so that future visitors will know this was a valid solution.