# Programmatically check a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I am reading values from a database (boolean) and if true, I want it to check a checkbox, and if false, keep the checkbox unchecked.  The lines look like this: `cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(1).Selected = track_usage`

In this case, `track_usage` is a boolean value.

This way does not actually create the check mark in the checkbox like I wanted it to.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Than what happens that you did not expect?

Comment: Is your track_usage = false? :-)

Comment: I want the check box to have the check and be viewed as selected for other parts of the program.  I expected that by setting it to true, it would be true, but it's not.

Comment: @Steve -> No, it is not false

Comment: FindByValue defaults to look for a string value. Passing it 1 might not give you the result you are looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue.aspx

Comment: @A.Still The `1` is a String.  I changed the values to numbers to mirror the physical form I'm developing from.  Do you know how I would go about getting the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Why can't you use the `checkbox.checked =true/false` property? you should post more code to tell us what variables you are using.

Comment: @Subs I don't have a `checkbox.checked` property.  Code here: http://pastebin.ca/2149545

Comment: I think you are using checkedlistbox. In that case to check an item at say index 1, you would say `CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, True)`

Comment: @Subs I don't have `CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked()`.  I only have `SetMetaTable` and `SetRenderMethodDelegate`.

Comment: Please post your `Form` details and tell me which checkbox you are trying to check/uncheck.

Comment: @Subs 

vb code here: http://pastebin.ca/2149545

html here: http://pastebin.ca/2149566

Comment: @Subs I'm trying to check a box or leave it unchecked based on the boolean data that comes out of the database.

Comment: Have you tried using `cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue(1).Checked = track_usage`..

Comment: @I.am.WritZ I don't have a `Checked` option

Comment: @Kruug The code you posted doesn't give any information about the controls you use on Form. You should also point out where your checkbox is in that code.

Comment: @Subs There's many.  Every time it states `<asp:CheckBoxList ID="<name here>" runat="server">`

Comment: Ok! the Code I found working is `cblEnergy.SetItemChecked(1, track_usage)`...Please Check This Code Out..

Comment: @I.am.WritZ Subs already pointed that out...not available.

Comment: Yes I saw that..But there is no other answer available at the moment else that one..
Can You Do `cblEnergy.Items(1).Selected = track_usage`??

Comment: @I.am.WritZ Still did not work.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and these are Web Form's in Visual Basic.  I don't know if I don't have the right modules available or something, but it's really starting to frustrate me...

Comment: The last hope is to use `cblEnergy.Items.Item(1).Selected = track_usage` as mentioned [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.item)

Answer (score 0):

If cb1Energy is `CheckBoxList` then you would use:

```
  Dim li_chkbox = cblEnergy.Items.FindByValue("1")
  If (li_chkbox != null) then
     li_chkbox.Selected = track_usage
  End if
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is different than how I have it...care to explain?

Comment: It all depends if you can show me what code you wrote in `<asp/>`

Comment: Honestly, all of the code is posted on pastebin.  My VB code: http://pastebin.ca/2149545  The HTML: http://pastebin.ca/2149566

Comment: Well, now i see the new link 149566

Comment: ` <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblEnergy" runat="server">`
            `<asp:ListItem Value="1"> Track electricity usage, fuel usage, and natural gas usage and share data with employees</asp:ListItem>`
            `<asp:ListItem Value="2"> Develop a policy/procedure strategy to conserve energy/increase renewable energy use</asp:ListItem>`  You did use a string - `"1"` , `"2"` in the ListItem Value. Try the change and see whether it works.

Comment: Facepalm mode initiated...testing it now.

Comment: Well, it worked as `Value(1)` when I was writing to the database.  It still doesn't work as `Value("1")` when reading from the database.

Comment: maybe your `track_usage` variable is `false`. You can test it out giving `True`

Comment: alright...this is irritating...when hard coding `True` it works.  When I grab a boolean value from the database, it doesn't work...VB automatically turns a 1 into True, correct?

Comment: see this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621037/casting-a-boolean-to-an-integer-returns-1-for-true