# Why is MS access boolean true -1 rather than 1 or true?

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

When I run a query in MS Access I can happily use a query like this:

```
SELECT clients.* FROM clients WHERE active=True;
```

or

```
SELECT clients.* FROM clients WHERE active=-1;
```

but not

```
SELECT clients.* FROM clients WHERE active=1;
```

In addition, say I want to query the database using PDO I might use a prepared statement:

```
$db->prepare('SELECT clients.* FROM clients WHERE active=:isactive;');
$db->bindValue(':isactive', True); //Does not work
$db->bindValue(':isactive', 1); //Does not work
$db->bindValue(':isactive', -1); //Does work
```

So even though `true` works when sending a plain query to Access, if binding only `-1` or `0` will work for boolean.

Why is this and why is `-1` representative of `true` when `1` usually means `true` in other languages/databases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't seem to find the exact source this is from, but I remember reading about this a while ago on I think MSDN. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621069/1053938) has a technical description of Visual Basic's boolean `true`, which applies to Access as well.

If I remember correctly, it's because -1 is represented in binary with every bit set to 1 (`1111 1111`), while +1 only has the least significant bit set to 1 with all the rest 0 (`0000 0001`). Because `false` is represented as 0 (`0000 0000`), it's very easy to change between `true` and `false` using a bitwise NOT, but if `true` was anything else, a bitwise NOT would result in something that isn't `false`. Also, using bitwise AND to check for truth on any truthy value would work, while if true was `0000 0001` it would not.

Comment: That seems very logical. Obviously Access can cope with being fed a `true` in a normal statement but binding queries cannot so creates a problem unless you feed it the proper value. `<>0` seems like a good workaround for `true` as @ChristianSpecht mentioned

Comment: Yea, Christian is correct about that. I just figured I'd answer the second part of your question.

Comment: +1 Another way of looking at it is that a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed integer that is only one bit long can only be one of two values: 0 or -1.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a better answer to "Why is this" than Dale Wilson already said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17368001/6884), but it's quite simple to circumvent this problem:

**Just get used to use `WHERE active <> 0` in your queries.**

I'm using MS Access (where `True` is `-1`) and MS SQL Server (where `True` is `1`) and checking `<> 0` is the easiest way that always works.

Comment: Or just `WHERE Active` (I haven't tested this with my SQL Server tables, but `WHERE ACTIVE` and `WHERE NOT ACTIVE` would do the trick I think

Comment: @Scotch Yes, having just tested, it seems if you have a boolean field you can query it just by going `SELECT * FROM table WHERE booleanfield` which will give you all rows where `booleanfield = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to be facetious, but the answer is "because that's the way they did it."   Your statement that 1 usually means true in other languages is not correct.   In C/C++ for example,  false is defined as ==0 and true is defined as !=0.

That's why you can say if(pointer) { ...}

Comment: Fair enough but `1!=0` so should surely return true. This is not the case in my question - no results are given, whether true or false. Basically 1 != true or false

Comment: Rule of thumb: Test boolean values, don't compare them.   For example, don't say if(testFunction() == true), just say if(testFunction())   This gets messy when you are trying to simulate exclusive or  (if(function1() != function2()) The safe and correct way to do this is slightly more verbose:  if function1() then ! function2() else function2() is guaranteed to call each function once and give you the exclusive or of the results.