# Validate Date entered into cell

Tags: sql, excel, vba, date, validation

I have a workbook with a field for a user to enter a date.  In testing, I entered 11/31/21 which is not a valid date.  I thought I would test for valid date entry and can't seem to make it work.  I am trying to use IsDate to check and must being doing something wrong.  I tried setting my cell value as both date and string with no luck.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PCell As Range
    Dim Edate As Date
   
    
    Set PCell = Range("S2")
        Edate = Range("S2") 
    
If Not Application.Intersect(PCell, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
    If IsDate(Edate) = 1 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - SelectedDataByDate").Refresh
Else
MsgBox ("You have entered an invalide date.")
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: November does have 30 days... So why is it not a valid date?

Comment: Good catch.  I updated the question to 11/31.

Comment: First `Dim EDate as Variant` and also True in VBA is possibly not 1: Just use `If IsDate(EDate) Then …` .See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621037/casting-a-boolean-to-an-integer-returns-1-for-true

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
Edate = Range("S2")
```

Should be

```
Edate = Range("S2").value
```

Comment: Being explicit about the `.Value` is a good idea, but it won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. @DS_London, it was the case that VBA did not use 1 but rather True and False.

This code ran as expected.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PCell As Range
    Dim Edate As Variant
       
    
    Set PCell = Range("S2")
        Edate = Range("S2")
        
   
    
If Not Application.Intersect(PCell, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
    If IsDate(Edate) = True Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - SelectedDataByDate").Refresh
Else
MsgBox ("You have entered an invalide date.")
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it's working: you can just use `If IsDate(Edate) then ...`. `IsDate()` already returns a  Boolean so you don't need the `=True` test.